# How to access httpcontext in all razorcomponents in mudblazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have created a mudblazor application and created an cshtml page as authentication provider and into it .CS file I have declared all logic to get jwt token response and their roles. Now I am trying to set the same using below:-

Httpcontext.Session.SetString("authentication", "true");

But if I try to use that httpcontext on different pages like my navmenu.razor page or any other razor page this httpcontext is not accessible.

Comment: Could you provide some code samples that demonstrate your problem? That might help people provide helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with using `IHttpContextAccessor` and it works to access session in different components.
program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
...
app.UseSession();
```

Home.razor

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor accessor
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        accessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("authentication", "true");
    }
}
```

Counter.razor

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor accessor
authentication:
@accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("authentication")
```

Test
[image]

Comment: Hey Qiang , thanks for the solution but the things is my whole auth code is in a CS file of cshtml page now I want to create these http context string there and want to access all pages IT is not a razor page where my auth code is

Comment: @ShianJA Are you using .net8?